# Process records in batch with one record parent at time

Tags: apex, batch

I have a requirement to process all records of the same parent field in a row. Have you an idea how to do this?
Exple :
need to get all contacts,
I want to do some modification and give a rank to contacts and insert other related records of the same account
I tried this code but it doesnt work

```
public without sharing class AP23_myBatch implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult>,Database.Stateful {
    public Boolean isActive;       
    public AP23_myBatch(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive= isActive;
    }
        
    public Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext context)//define context of records we'll process
    {  
        return new AP29_AggregateResultIterable(getQueryByBoolean (isActive));
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<AggregateResult> records){
        //Some code
    }   
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
      //an other job to launch
    }
    private String getQueryByBoolean (Boolean isActive){
        String result = '';
        if (isActive){
            result ='SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE isActive__c = false GROUP BY AccountId ,Id Order BY AccountId';
        }
        else {
            result ='SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE isActive__c = true  GROUP BY AccountId ,Id Order BY AccountId';
        }
        System.debug('result: ' + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
public class AP29_AggregateResultIterable implements Iterable<AggregateResult> {
    private String query;
    
    public AP29_AggregateResultIterable(String soql){
    query = soql;
    }
    
    
    public Iterator<AggregateResult> Iterator(){
    return new AP30_AggregateResultIterator(query);
    }
}
```

```
public class AP30_AggregateResultIterator implements Iterator<AggregateResult> {

    AggregateResult [] results {get;set;}
    
    // tracks which result item is returned
    
    Integer index {get; set;}
    
    public AP30_AggregateResultIterator(String query) {
    index = 0;
    results = Database.query(query);
    }
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return results != null && !results.isEmpty() && index < results.size();
        }
        
        
        public AggregateResult next(){
        return results[index++];
        }
}
```

Comment: Batches don't need to be global.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to describe specifically what is not working.  Include error messages or debug log entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main query of the batch should retrieve all the accounts to be processed.  Within the main query you should include a subquery to get the account's contacts to be processed.  Then for each account in the list, loop through the contacts list to do your processing, and then you can update the contacts.